# Is there a way to make build of any branch in TeamCity without creating additional parameters?

Tags: git, build, teamcity

I created the build that can build any branch with dependency from one of the previous build. Now I'm using `%teamcity.build.branch%` in the dependency branch name. But this parameter is not defined when I build it for master. Is there a way to add something like `%teamcity.build.branch% || %[defaultBranch]%` without creating additional parameters? If not, then what is the easiest way to make something like this? Now I can build any branch except the default branch. In this case, I should manually select dependency for the default branch.

Comment: Why do you use parameters for a branch name? If you have a snapshot dependency between builds, it'll start on the same branch without any parameters. Could you please describe your setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using TeamCity not correctly.

You should add [Snapshot Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/snapshot-dependencies.html) to your parent configuration.

let's consider the **Deploy(child)** configuration and **Build(parent)** configuration. 
We need to pass the branch name from Deploy to Build.
If you want to pass the branch, you should add `Snapshot Dependencies` in the  Deploy.

So, edit the **Deploy configuration**. Go to **Dependencies** -> **Add new snapshot dependency**.

- Select the Build from the drop-down,
- check `Enforce revisions synchronization`
- I recommend check `Do not run new build if there is a suitable one` and `Only use successful builds from suitable ones`

And now you can run a custom build of Deploy and select the needed branch in the *Changes* tab